# Display inner html with drupal_render()

Tags: html, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-render

How do you display inner html tags using drupal_render() in drupal 7 ? For example, I have an  tag inside a  and I would like to display just the  and not the entire  , what do I do ?

Comment: I guess nested html is a more apt term.

Answer (score 0):

As i know, Drupal can´t do that, instead, you can wrap the inner html tags in another theme function (or template) and call it from the theme function (or template) where are the outer tags and where you need only inner tags